# How to access markup twig variable from code in OctoberCMS

Tags: laravel, twig, octobercms

I'm trying to access variable from markup (Twig) in octoberCMS code module. This variable is printed in loop by plugin builder.

I have this variable in markup:

```
{% set frontId = record.id %}
{{frontId}}
```

And I want to access {{**frontId**}} variable it in code module.

```
function onStart()
{
    $this["slots"] =  Db::table('oblikovanje_izobrazevanja_vnos')->where('id', $frontId)->value('free_slots');
    echo $frontId;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, unfortunately you can not pass variables from `Markup` to `Code` section. Because `Code` section as whole executed before `Markup` so you can not do that.

**It seems you are using Builder's `Record details` component so you must be passing `:id` from url**

> **Solution 1 [ use param ]**

```php
function onStart() { // you can use onEnd as well
    $frontId = $this->param('id'); // this will get :id param from url

    // now slots variable are available in `Markup section`    
    $this["slots"] =  Db::table('oblikovanje_izobrazevanja_vnos')->where('id', $frontId)->value('free_slots');

}
```

> **Solution 2 [ you can use global component array with its alias name, make sure to use  onEnd life-cycle hook ]**

```php
function onEnd () { // you must use onEnd as at this moment all components are initialized properly 

    // we can access component from $this->components with alias name and get its details
    $frontId = $this->components['builderDetails']->record->id;

    // now slots variable are available in `Markup section`    
    $this["slots"] =  Db::table('oblikovanje_izobrazevanja_vnos')->where('id', $frontId)->value('free_slots');

}
```

> **Reference Screenshot**

[image]

if any doubts please comment.